# jpa entitymanager contains always returns false

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a simple test case where I save an object and then test if the object is present in db. but the contains method always returns false. The object is saved in the database

```
 User entity = new User();
    entity.setName("test");
    User result = ObjectManager.save(entity);

    boolean exists = ObjectManager.contains(result);

    assertTrue(exists);

@Override
public boolean contains(T obj) throws DataStoreException {
    try {
        return entityManager.contains(obj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new DataStoreException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the EntityManager [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html):

> Check if the instance is a managed
>   entity instance belonging to the
>   current persistence context.

So it does not check if its in database. May be you have detached the entity in the save method or somehow its not in the current persistence context.

Use find or get to verify existence in db.

Comment: can you give me a test case that I can use to verify the contains() method. I was under the impression that once you get an object using find, it should in managed state.

Comment: Your impression is correct, it should be in managed state. But on "detaching" an entity its no longer managed. You can detach by calling entitymanager.detach or entitymanager.clear. Also calling entitymanager.remove will remove it from context as well as from db. In all these cases, if you call contains it will return false